# How to count no grid columns in grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to count, kindly give advice or code. I want to count from above big gridview and display in below small gridview, can u help me how to count?

```
public void fillgridview()
{
    string prjname = ddlproject.SelectedItem.Text;
    string frmDt = txtfrmdate.Text.ToString();
    string Todt = txtEndDate.Text.ToString();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();



    Dap_Proj.Fill(ds);

    GVKeywordReport.DataSource = ds;
    GVKeywordReport.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You have a serious SQL injection problem in your code.

Comment: Use group by compare-prev on your resultselt and bind query result to second grid. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Comment: i didnt get ...wat sql injection problem in my code ? can u elaaborate plz?

Answer (score 0):

You have to advance throught data from the given DataSet in form like

```
string selectQuery = "username='" + username + "' AND " + "projectType='" + projectType + "'";

ds.Tables[0].Select(selectQuery, sortField);
```

Comment: +keep between calls to function in DataSet in Sesson valiables for ASP.NET 2.0, or in internal state for ASP.NET > 2.0 (MVC)

Comment: +add a check for Page IsPostBack when call to function is made in Page Load routine (for ASP.NET 2.0)